# Double formatting doesn't work

Tags: java, double

I used the same code previously and it used to work. But now it doesn't work and say doesn't show 3.0 like 3.00. Any idea?

```
double result=3.0;
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(result));
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What **does** it show?

Comment: It shows 3 instead of 3.00

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [`DecimalFormat` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), you should use a `0` character instead of a `#` character to indicate a digit that must be present, even if it's a zero.  Try

```
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("#.00").format(result));
```

Comment: @MonaJalal I'm sure it wasn't.  A `#` after the decimal doesn't show a valueless zero.

Comment: Maybe because the numbers were like 3.2 ish?

Comment: @MonaJalal Previously, you may have had a number such as `3.14` that would have "worked", because each digit would have been necessary anyway.

Comment: Yeah, if you try `new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(3.2)` you'll get `3.2`, not `3.20`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

System.out.printf("%2d%n", result );